# Booting 18.04 with overlay fillesystem

Tags: 18.04, overlayfs

1. I have an arm based embedded target with emmc and sd card.

   2. The 18.04 rootfs is on `/dev/mmcblk0p2`. Kernel version is 4.14 and overlay filesystem is enabled. Kernel and device tree are on `/dev/mmcblk0p1`
   3. Before making it read only, installed overlayfs package with apt-get and set `overlayroot=tmpfs` in `/etc/overlayroot.conf` file.
   4. using uboot to load kernel and bootargs are: `earlyprintk loglevel=8 uio_pdrv_genirq.of_id=generic-uio root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 ro rootwait rootfstype=ext4`

After above setup: I still see rootfs is mounted on `/dev/mmcblk0p2`.

Am I missing anything?